# Линия-полукруг на яндекс. картах

Tags: javascript, php, яндекс-карты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, был у кого опыт по созданию подобного на яндекс.картах? С прямо линией проблем нет, а вот как выгнуть это дело? Одна точка константная, а вторая всегда будет меняться.

Comment: Встроенных в API Яндекс Карт методов для этого нет. Нужно будет использовать svg или canvas поверх карты, как вариант. Получить пиксельные координаты точек в блоке карты для этого можно через https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.Converter.html#method_detail__globalToPage . А вот как вы будете определять, куда и как изгибать линию при различном расположении точек - уже ваш алгоритм нужен.

Comment: Спасибо! ) Так и думал, что всё не так просто ...